# could not load file or assembly Nlog.web.aspnetcore or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, logging, nlog

I am getting the yellow screen of death for my asp.net application which has the NLog implementation enabled. The error is "Could not load file or assembly NLog.Web.AspNetCore or one of its dependencies" while initializing the logger. I followed all basic setup rules for the logging from NLog in my asp.net application and it still fails to work. The log files are not written too. I am confused how to troubleshoot further.

Here are the things I did but no luck,

1. Enabled exceptions for NLog = > Thus I found that Logger has a problem loading NLog.Web.AspNetCore. It says the system cannot find the file specified.
2. The extensions section in the Nlog config was there by default and it contains NLog.Web.AspNetCore however my application isn't based on asp.net core.
3. the file path of the log is set as name="MyLog" type="File" fileName="log.txt" along with layout and createDirs = true in the target section.
4. Rules of the log is also defined. logger name = "*" minlevel=trace writeTo="MyLog".

Some how I couldn't get this working for past 2 days. Please guide me with some hints to resolve this problem. Appreciate your time to help!

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have nLog.config file and if yes right click on the config file in solution explorer and then click properties and set the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`

Comment: I tried now, but it didn't work too. Still i get the could not load file or assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the following is true:

> however my application isn't based on asp.net core.

Then you should stop your attempts in trying to load `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` (Remove from it from `<extensions>`). And remove any references to layout-renderers that begins with  `${aspnet-`

Comment: thank you. this fixed my problem. I removed the references and also updated the layout-renderers according to the syntax.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me, as well. What I do not understand is why it used to work since September 2021 till yesterday, without any changes to the configuration or the invoking application. Mystery.